# Error while applying texture in threejs: "Cannot read property 'x' of undefined"

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to map a texture onto a square in threejs.

Here's my code (coffeescript)

```
texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture "my/texture/file.jpg"

myMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial
  map:texture
  side:THREE.DoubleSide

squareGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
squareGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-1.0,  1.0, 0.0));
squareGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( 1.0,  1.0, 0.0));
squareGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( 1.0, -1.0, 0.0));
squareGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0));
squareGeometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2));
squareGeometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(2, 3, 0));

myMesh = new THREE.Mesh(squareGeometry, myMaterial);
myMesh.position.set(1.5, 0.0, 4.0);
scene.add(myMesh);
```

When I render this in a `CanvasRenderer` I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```

If I try a `WebGLRenderer` I get

```
[.WebGLRenderingContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1
```

There's a live version of the code [here](http://cdpn.io/xneIl).

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is easier using `PlaneGeometry`. The code below works.

```
texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture textureFile

myMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial
  map:texture


planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1, 1 );


myMesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, myMaterial);
myMesh.position.set(-0.5, -0.5, 0.0);
scene.add(myMesh);
```

Here's a [live demo](http://cdpn.io/uFaAK).

Comment: Consider using `THREE.PlaneGeometry` -- much easier. Also, winding orders must be counter-clockwise. It is only because of the `DoubleSide` setting of your material that your code appears to work.

Comment: Good call. I've updated my answer with your suggestions.

Comment: Why are you reassigning UVs? Why is your material double-sided?

Comment: I was copying code from a tutorial. I only need to render the front side, so, you're right, I don't need double-sided rendering. Thanks!